# cannot convert argument 1 from wchar to lpcstr

Tags: c++

Can't change the whole project to unicode.

[image]

```
void CreateDir(string dirname)
{
    char my_dir[247];
    WCHAR wcmy_dir[UNLEN+1];sprintf_s(my_dir, dirname.c_str()); 
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, my_dir, (int)strlen(my_dir)+1, wcmy_dir, 
    sizeof(wcmy_dir)/sizeof(wcmy_dir[0]));
    CreateDirectory(wcmy_dir, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Have you done any research on this issue?

Comment: Make sure the character set for your project is set to 'Use Unicode Character Set', see: https://godbolt.org/z/Bpy3p5

Comment: The current version of the project you use is not unicode and that's why CreateDirectory is expanded to CreateDirectoryA not CreateDirectoryW.

Comment: If I change project to unicode I get like 10 other errors in the project

Comment: Then those need to be fixed, if you want to end up with a Unicode build.

Comment: If Unicode is not defined, then call `CreateDirectory(dirname.c_str(), NULL);`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thank you!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani better would be to call `CreateDirectoryA()` explicitly instead: `CreateDirectoryA(dirname.c_str(), NULL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is not configured to use Unicode, so `CreateDirectory()` will map to `CreateDirectoryA()` instead of `CreateDirectoryW()` like your code is assuming. Passing a `WCHAR` string to `CreateDirectoryA()` is indeed an error.

Since you are not actually calling `CreateDirectoryW()`, you don't need to call `MultiByteToWideChar()` at all.  Just call `CreateDirectoryA()` explicitly, passing it your input `string` as-is:

```
void CreateDir(string dirname)
{
    CreateDirectoryA(dirname.c_str(), NULL);
}
```

Internally, it will convert the `char` data to `WCHAR` using `CP_ACP` and then call `CreateDirectoryW()` for you.

If you ever decide to update your project to use Unicode but do not change your function to use `wstring`, this same code will still work without change.

If you ever decide to change your function to use `wstring` instead, simply call `CreateDirectoryW()` explicitly to match:

```
void CreateDir(wstring dirname)
{
    CreateDirectoryW(dirname.c_str(), NULL);
}
```